# How to remap/switch OPTION and COMMAND keys in Macosx when using Microsoft remote desktop connection

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, macbook

I use MacBook pro, and I need to use RDP to connect my workstation.
But every time when I connect to the workstation and press the key "OPTION" (it is WIN key at the same position if it is a windows keyboard), the windows start menu will *not* popup. Only when I press "COMMAND" (it is ALT key in windows keyboard), the start menu is pop-up.

So, I want to switch option and command keys when I use RDP. how can we approach that? thx.

Comment: Speaking as someone who has been doing this for over 20 years - it's far simpler to just learn the difference.

Comment: @Tetsujin could u please share more information? thx.

Comment: Cmd=WinKey, Opt=Alt. Just learn the difference in placement, it doesn't take long.